# php.using hyperlink update not a submit button

Tags: php

how yo use hypelink update to update values inside Mysql database via textboxes .

Comment: do you mean adding an onclick function to submit a form?

Comment: Please be more specific. Include some code samples.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for executing some kind of live php. But... could you **describe** your problem? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite ambiguous but as a rough guess I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.formName.submit();">Submit Form</a>
```

Obviously replace 'formName' with the name of your form and when you click on the link the form will be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge gap between "hyperlink" and "update database".

Fundamentally, your hyperlink will cause the browser to send request to a web server. Some server-side software (PHP) will respond to the request, open a connection to the database, generate and send a query to the database, interpret the database's response, and send a formatted response back to the browser.

It is impossible to answer more specifically, as your question is far, far too broad.

Which part of the above process have you tried? Which part are you stuck on?